# BroadcastReceiver onReceive method ends before thread does

Tags: android, parse-platform, broadcastreceiver

I have an asynchronous method in my BoradcastReceiver's onReceive method.

Specifically I am doing a `pinInBackground` with a `ParseObject` from the ParseSDK

The callback in my asynchronous method never gets called, leading me to believe that the BroadcastReceiver is no longer executing things in the onReceive method any longer

Is there a way to manually kill an onReceive method or override the way it dies? Alternatively I could use the receiver to start a service instead, which I can control, but any other insight appreciated

Comment: Start a service from your broadcast receiver and do the processing there...it could even be a intent service

Answer (score 0):

> I have an asynchronous method in my BoradcastReceiver's onReceive method.

If this is a manifest-registered receiver, please do not do this.

> The callback in my asynchronous method never gets called, leading me to believe that the BroadcastReceiver is no longer executing things in the onReceive method any longer

If the call is asynchronous, `onReceive()` returns, the `BroadcastReceiver` is discarded, and (if there's nothing else going on) your process is likely to be terminated in short order, to free up system RAM.

> Is there a way to manually kill an onReceive method or override the way it dies?

Not really.

> Alternatively I could use the receiver to start a service instead, which I can control

This is the correct solution. You need the service as a means of telling Android that you are doing work, so Android will not be as aggressive about terminating your process. There, if your Parse work can be done synchronously, use an `IntentService`. If the only Parse option is an asynchronous call, use a regular `Service`, where you call `stopSelf()` on the service when you get your Parse results back and no longer need the service.

If this Parse work may take an extended period of time (say, 15+ seconds), you're also going to need to consider a `WakeLock` and perhaps a `WifiLock`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `IntentService` and make your BroadcastReceiver a wakeful one, `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`. Then you can do your work and release the wake lock.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent service = new Intent(context, MyIntentService.class);
    // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
    startWakefulService(context, service);
}
```

In your Intent Service:

```
// Release the wake lock provided by the BroadcastReceiver.
MyWakefulReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
```